# URL value and Javascript value into Json of Node.js Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, url

Need help with the values from separate places to make up the Json in the server.js of the Express app (before viewed in the .ejs)

The **first values** are from the URL and needs to go into the Json (id in first entry, shown here as number 113; and name, shown here as daisy)

–> from the URL:

https://mywebsite.com/?id=113&name=daisy&image=https://mywebsite.com/m81.png

–> into the Json of server.js:

```
const chosenItems = new Map([
  [113, { item: 302, name: "daisy" }]
])
```

And the **second value**, shown here as number 302, is from the “item” id generated in a separate .js javascript (which extracts it from a database in the back end.)

```
document.getElementById("item").innerHTML = arr[0].v;
```

The first id from the URL (113) and the item from the javascript (302) is critical.

Is there a simple way to get these values directly into this Json format?

Then the name value from the URL, along with the related &image, since this all runs through Express’ View engine, ejs, to the front end.

Many thanks

Andi

–

I tried this for the **first values** from the URL:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  const id = req.query.id;
  const name = req.query.name;

  res.send([
    [ id, { 'name': name }]
  ])
});
```

which outputs this into the browser:

```
[["113",{"name":"daisy"}]]
```

but I can't get it to only fill the Json in the server.js here:

```
const chosenItems = new Map([
  [id, { item: 'item', name: 'name' }]
])
```

to look / function like this

```
const chosenItems = new Map([
  [113, { item: 302, name: "daisy" }]
])
```

For the **second value**, I do not know how to integrate the "item" from the separate javascript, looked into a function for a getElementById but can't get it to work and now stuck.

Would very much appreciate help!

Comment: It's not clear at all how a value from **client-side** HTML / JS is supposed to reach your server when it's not part of a request. Where **exactly** is that `302` value supposed to come from? Do you even need that value on the server-side? Do you need any value on the server-side?

Comment: the 302 comes from the database on the back end server via fetch js